# Automatically import properties file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a properties file used for building in Ant containing variables that I want to add to Eclipse classpath. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Ideally I'd like to be able to add an argument to the command line and automatically import the values in the file.

Acceptable solutions also include the usage of a plugin that adds this functionality.

Example: 
test.propeties

```
MW_HOME=C:\\Program\\Oracle\\
TEST_HOME=C:\\temp\\
```

Comment: Would you also accept the other way around? Defining the class path in Eclipse and exporting it to the Ant script as some Ant properties?

Comment: @Bananeweizen That's not what I am looking for, but feel free to post it as an answer anyway. Future searches might lead someone here who wants to know just that.